# Conditional distribution for normal variable for range

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $X \sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y ~ \sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$ are Gaussians with correlation $\rho$. Then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) formula can be used to obtain the conditional density for $X | Y = y$.

Is there another nice formula for the conditional density $X | Y \geq y$ instead?

Comment: Sorry in general no. The conditional CDF is 
$\displaystyle \Pr\{X \leq x|Y \geq y\} = \frac {\Pr\{X \leq x, Y \geq y\}} {\Pr\{Y \geq y\}}$. After differentiating with respect to $x$, we got the conditional density which will involve the integral of a bivariate Gaussian density.

Comment: But how do you know that this integral doesn't evaluate to something nicer, like it does for $Pr(X \leq x|Y=y)$?

Comment: The integral of Gaussian density has no closed form except the integral limit is at the mean or infinities. I have no nice proof to you for this fact. So usually people can express the result in terms of some function like $\Phi$ which has no closed form available.